# SDKイニシャル時のshコマンドでエラー

Tags: spresense

SDKイニシャル時に、shコマンドを使って、スクリプトファイルを実行しております。

```
sh script1 &
sh script2 &
sh script3 &
sh script4 &
sh script5 &
sh script6 &
```

script5と、script6で、以下のエラーが表示され、実行できておりませんでした。

```
nsh: sh: fopen failed: 23
```

script1～4までは、エラーなく実行できております。

どこかに上限数の設定がありますでしょうか？
（SDKコンフィグ設定でNSH Libraryあたりを探してみましたが見つかりませんでした。。。）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

実際に試してみましたが、自分の環境では特に問題なく6つ以上のスクリプトでも実行できています。質問のエラーは、スクリプトの中身に依存していることはないでしょうか。

```
nsh: sh: fopen failed: 23
```

23は、ENFILEエラーなのでファイルのopen数が上限に達しているようです。

```c
#define ENFILE              23
#define ENFILE_STR          "File table overflow"
```

もしかしたら使用しているSpresense SDKのバージョンが古かったりしませんか？
昔のバージョンは1つのスレッド/タスクからのファイルopen数に制限がありましたが、最新のバージョン(SDKv2.3.0以降のバージョン)だとその制約はなくなっているはず。もし古いバージョンを使用している場合は、最新のバージョンに更新して試してみることをオススメします。